# Sorting by property of foreign key object

Tags: entity-framework, linq, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core

I'm making a third party app for a game.

In my domain I have the class 'player'. Players can attack/defend attacks of other players and while doing so they earn attacking/defending points. The API of the game is pretty awful (Online txt files in csv format) so there's little manipulation I can do other than bulk insert the files into my database and work from there.

Doing so I have a player table and a Points_Att table. In my EF configuration Player owns one Points_Att and Points_Att has one property: points. And each player has a 'Player_Att' object.

I'm trying to get the top X attackers from the database. But I can't sort on Player_Att.points, I tried the following code:

`return _players.Where("conditions").OrderBy(p => p.Points_Att.Points).Take(X).ToList();`

This gives me an array of the first X players in my database, it doesn't sort. I tried changing the Player_Att object to an int which would be easier to work with but my limited knowledge seems to stop me from doing so...

So basically I need to sort on player.Points_Att.Points or I need an int object rather than a Player_Att object.

If anything isn't clear please feel free to ask, I browsed my problem for a couple of hours now and i'm not getting any further.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Models:

```
public class Player
{
    public Player_Att PointsAttacking { get; private set; }
}

public class Player_Att
{
    public int Points { get; private set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
internal class PlayerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Player>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Player> builder)
        {


            builder.OwnsOne(p => p.PointsAttacking).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


        }

public class Player_AttConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Player_Att>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Player_Att> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Player_Att");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `Points` property? Including the classes in question would be helpful.

Comment: I edited the initial post with more code fragments, I limited the fragments to the code that applies to my problem. The points property is an int. I can include it just fine I just can't sort on it.

Comment: Ok, first this is EF Core. Second, `OwnsOne` is for different purpose - [owned entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities). Basically embedding the entity properties into the owner entity type table, which apparently is not what you have. I'm surprised it even allows such configuration. Most likely it's a matter of proper configuration. I think we need [mcve]. Also the exact EF Core version used.

Comment: In my database Player_Att has the primary keys of Player and Points as a normal column. I don't fully recall why I used OwnsOne instead of HasOne, I think HasOne gave an error of some sort but I programmed that a while back, this is a sideproject I work on for fun/educative purpose. I'm using EF Core 2.2, going to give the link you sent a look.

Comment: if you are looking for a larger in to get you need OrderByDescending.